# Implementation of push notification in iphone with out APN(Apple push notification service or server)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

am developing push notification application for iphone3,4...   what is the way to implement the push notification web server with out using Apple Push Notification Service. Some suggested to use like VOIP etc... IS there any other way to implement it ?